# Check with textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this question. I have a input type text and a  button. Like this html:

```
<form id="browser-form">
    <div class="filebrowser">
        <input type="text" id="browser-filepath">
    </div>
    <div class="upload submit"> 
        <a href="#" id="browser-submit" class="button">Uploaden</a> 
    </div>
</form>
```

But the question is. When the input type is empty. Je can not click on the button. When the input type is fil. Than you can click on the button. How can i fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: Use a button to submit forms, not an `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, I think you want to prevent the link from doing anything unless the `input` has a value. If that's correct, then you can do this:

```
$("#browser-submit").click(function(e) {
    if(!$("#browser-filepath").val()) {
       e.preventDefault();
    } 
});
```

`preventDefault` is a method of the event object which, as the name suggests, prevents the default action of an event (in this case, following the link).

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/SVz2c/) of the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
function UpdateSubmitButton() {
var oTextBox = document.getElementById("browser-filepath");
var oButton = document.getElementById("browser-submit");

if(oTextBox.value == "") {
oButton.disabled = true;
}
else {
oButton.disabled = false;
}
}
```

Add an onchange="UpdateSubmitButton()" section to your text box, and you might want to add onload="UpdateSubmitButton()" to your document body.

This should do the trick.